# Windbg set conditional breakpoint

Tags: windbg

Can't get this to work. I want to set a conditional breakpoint in Windbg with the condition to be when eax is 11h (17). I tried:

bu xxxxxxxx ".if(eax != 17){gc}"

bu xxxxxxxx ".if(@eax != 17){gc}"

bp xxxxxxxx "j (eax == 17) ''; 'gc' "

bp xxxxxxxx "j (@eax == 17) ''; 'gc' "

Nothing works. Thanks in advance

Comment: Windbg default radix is 16 (hex), thus 17 - without any prefix - would be `0x17` (23). You need to specify a number prefix if you want to stick with decimal (`0n` ; e.g. `0n17`) or use the [`n`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/n--set-number-base-) command to change the default radix. Best way to not deal with this kind of errors is to always prefix your numbers with `0x` even if you know the default radix is 16.

Comment: Thank you Neitsa! This is it. I will check if it works and let you know tomorrow, I'm going asleep now, really tired

Comment: Thanks again. It worked! You're a genius! You can repost your answer in the main answer frame so that I can check your answer as best.